# How to pass or send data from recyclerview adapter to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How to pass data from recyclerview adapter to fragment and what i have to write the code in fragment to receive data.I have already check the links in this website but unfortunately unable to get correct code.
Below is the code

> ExampleAdapter.Java

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item,viewGroup,false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh=new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder exampleViewHolder, int i) {
        final ExampleItem currentItem=mExampleList.get(i);
        exampleViewHolder.mTextView.setText(currentItem.getmText());
        exampleViewHolder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // pass the data to the fragment
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }
    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);
        }
    }
    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList){
              this.mExampleList=exampleList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can pass data by attaching a callback into your adapter:

**Create an interface**:

```
interface OnTextClickListener {
    void onTextClick(ExampleItem data);
}
```

**Delegate the callback**:

```
class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    List<ExampleItem> items;
    OnTextClickListener listener;

    ExampleAdapter(List<ExampleItem> items, OnTextClickListener listener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Say you want to pass an ExampleItem back to the fragment...
                ExampleItem data = items.get(position);
                listener.onTextClick(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Implement the fragment with the interface**:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment implements OnTextClickListener {

    public onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(this));
    }

    void onTextClick(ExampleItem data) {
        // Now you can do however you want with the data here...
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got: " + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: What to write in listener.onTextClick(...) in Adapter and void onTextClick(Object data) {
        // Data received from the adapter }
   in Fragment

Comment: @mohammednabil You can pass anything you want as argument in `listener.onTextClick()`, then you can deal with the data in the callback `onTextClick()` later. I have updated my answer, so I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, very nice and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options;

**Using `SharedPreferences`**:

```
Context myContext = exampleViewHolder.itemView.getContext()

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("DeviceToken", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("YourKeyNameHere", currentItem.getmText()); // or add toString() after if needed
editor.apply();
```

<sub>To get:</sub>

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DeviceToken", MODE_PRIVATE);
String deviceToken = prefs.getString("YourKeyNameHere", null); // get it here
```

**Using `Intent`**: (If you want to start the another `Activity` when you pass the data)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myContext , SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_TEXT", currentItem.getmText());
startActivity(intent); // if needed, add myContext before starting myContext.startActivity...
```

<sub>To get:</sub>

```
String extraText = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_TEXT");
```

Comment: Its showing "Cannot resolve method getsharedreferences(java.lang.String, int) in ExampleAdapter.java and also in Fragment.java

Comment: The second parameter is `int`,  So if you use `currentItem.getmText()`, like I said, add `toString()` after. Like this: `currentItem.getmText().toString()`

Comment: Its showing same cannot resolve mehod getsharedreference(java.lang.String,int) after typing current.getmText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

You have "ClickListener" in fragment.

for example.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ((ExampleAdapter) mAdapter).onItemClick(new RecyclerViewItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            //to do. ArrayList<> data.get(position).getYourItem();
        }
    });
}
```

And you must create interface RecyclerViewItemClick.java

```
public interface RecyclerViewItemClick {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
```

Last. ExampleAdapter.java add

```
public void onItemClick(RecyclerViewItemClick mclick){
   this.myClickListener = mclick;
}
```

ExampleViewHolder method add in

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I hope you solve this problem. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `IDataCollector` interface. Implement her in the `Fragment`, pass the `Fragment` reference as a constructor parameter, and use it inside the adapter

```
public interface IDataCollector {
    void setText(String text);
    void setAnything(Object anything);
}

// Fragment

public class Fragment implements IDataCollector {

    private void initView() {
        // Add this as a parameter
        ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(... , this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text){
        this.textField = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(Object anything){
        this.anything = anything;
    }
}

// Adapter code

// Constructor, parameters ommited
public ExampleAdapter(...., IDataCollector dataCollector) {
    this.dataCollector = dataCollector;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder exampleViewHolder, int i) {
    final ExampleItem currentItem=mExampleList.get(i);
    exampleViewHolder.mTextView.setText(currentItem.getmText());
    exampleViewHolder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataCollector.setText(((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.label1)).getText());
            ....
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through Interface you can solve this 
1. create an Interface in adapter , add required methods
2. call those methods in adapter wherever required 
3. implement the interface in fragment or activity, pass a context to the adapter

Comment: What 2 methods are required in interface and how to implement the interface in fragment.