# Closed fragment still appearing under base fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 5 fragments (home, settings, newPost, notifications and profile) inside my Main2Activity.

Inside `HomeFragment` I have a `RecyclerView` with a lot of post views, every post containing an "open" button which should open a `PostFragment`. After the `PostFragment` is opened I have 3 options to go back to `HomeFragment`: by tapping phone's 'back' button, tapping my post's XML "back" button or tapping `Home` from the `bottomNavView`. The problem is that after `PostFragment` disappears and my screen goes back to `HomeFragment`, `PostFragment` is still observable, but under `HomeFragment's RecyclerView`. How can I manage that?

This is how I open my PostFragment:

```
viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.seePostButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment newFragment = new PostFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

UPDATE:
It seems PostFragment will fully disappear if I press back one more time but it's not very efficient.
UPDATE 2.0:

```
    public void onBackPressed(){
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

Using this method: 
1.if I'm in PostFragment and tap Home, PostFragment remains observable under HomeFragment's RecyclerView
2.if I'm in PostFragment and tap phone's back button, the problem is not happening anymore
3.if I'm in PostFragment and tap posts's XML back button, to problem does not happen anymore

BUT, in my `ProfileFragment` I have a 2tabs (MyPosts and Posts I've Applied To) `TabView` connected to a viewPager that contains the posts. If I open one post and tap any of the three options I have mentioned earlier, HomeFragment pops up, having the Post observable under the recyclerView. From this point, any bottomNavItem I tap, the PostFragment will be observable.

HomeFragment with PostFragment being visible  between posts:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmbeg.jpg

PostFragment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmagy.jpg

ProfileFragment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNoeM.jpg

Tapping back from a PostFragment opened from ProfileFragment should get me back to ProfileFragment, not HomeFragment.

UPDATE 3:
I modified onBackPressed() to:

```
        FragmentTransaction transaction = 
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(this);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

Now if I tap Post's back button (not phone's) the Post is not visible anymore behind the RecyclerView. But if I use phone's back button, the problem is still there. I have to somehow include onBackPressed() in phone's Back button code..

UPDATE: Final edit, problem solved:
Because the Overrideable onBackPressed is only available in the activity that hosts the fragments I had to modify it there like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("POST") == null){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else{
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("POST"));
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This problem occurs in all 3 back options?

Comment: Please add your back press code

Comment: I tried to give more details.. I think the problem is somehow related to how the backstack handles the fragments

Comment: Try to add fragments instead of replace

Comment: same result in all cases

Comment: I made some changes, half of the problem was solved.. phone's back button is the only remaining problem

Comment: Make same changes in onbackpressed()

Comment: I did, I did, it;s finally working. Thank you very much for the help and sorry for the baggy post. If you want you can answer this post to get the green check mark, or how it;s called XD

Comment: You can checkmark your last question's answer which was given by me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432829/cant-open-a-fragment-from-another-fragment/61437267#61437267 Can you tell me how did it work? so that I can learn something from it :)

Comment: Ask me anything, anytime. I would love to help you :)