# How can I pass data from a recycler view button to fragment? [ kotlin or java]

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a Bottom sheet fragment that has two fragments and one of the fragments has a recycler view with a button inside it. What I need is that if a user clicks that button it will swipe to the second fragment and pass the title of the text view with it. everything is working great but I don't know how to use my idea of coding if that's possible. I tried looking for answers, but none of them worked for me.

What I need is

- Open a fragment from a button that's inside of a recycler view
- When the other fragment gets open, I need to show a title that I passed from recycler view

Any help would be appreciated / Please use java or kotlin

**My recycler view adapter**

```
    class tvTitleAdapter (val context: Context,val TITLE_LIST : ArrayList<TvTitlesViewModel>)
    :  RecyclerView.Adapter<tvTitleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.tv_titles_design, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return TITLE_LIST.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val tvShow: TvTitlesViewModel = TITLE_LIST[position]
        holder.titleShow.text = tvShow.title
        holder.description.text = tvShow.description
        holder.showImage.setImageResource(tvShow.title_image)
        holder.tvTitleExpand.setOnClickListener {
            holder.description.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.showImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.tvTitleButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
        holder.tvTitleButton.setOnClickListener {
            when(position){
                0->{
                    // I need to swipe to the other fragment and pass data to it from here if 
                     that's possible 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class ViewHolder(Itemview : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(Itemview){

        val titleShow = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTitle)
        val description = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDesription)
        val showImage = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tvImage)
        var tvTitleExpand = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.tvTitleExpand)
        val tvTitleButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tvTitleButton) // this is a button inside a recycler view
    }
}
```

**My fragment**

```
class TvTitlesFragment : Fragment() {

val TV_TITLE : ArrayList<TvTitlesViewModel> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tv_titles, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val adapter = tvTitleAdapter(context!!,TV_TITLE)
    tvTitles.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    tvTitles.setHasFixedSize(true)
    tvTitles.adapter = adapter
    tvShowTitles()
}
private fun tvShowTitles(){
    TV_TITLE.add(TvTitlesViewModel(R.drawable.abdelbasset_abdessamad, "برنامج على مائدة الأفطار", "برنامج على مائدة الافطار من تقديم الشيخ علي الطنطاوي رحمه الله, تم بث أول حلقة منه في عام 1960 م واستمر الى عام1992 م"))
    TV_TITLE.add(TvTitlesViewModel(R.drawable.abdelbasset_abdessamad, "برنامج على مائدة الأفطار", "برنامج على مائدة الافطار من تقديم الشيخ علي الطنطاوي رحمه الله, تم بث أول حلقة منه في عام 1960 م واستمر الى عام1992 م"))
    TV_TITLE.add(TvTitlesViewModel(R.drawable.abdelbasset_abdessamad, "برنامج على مائدة الأفطار", "برنامج على مائدة الافطار من تقديم الشيخ علي الطنطاوي رحمه الله, تم بث أول حلقة منه في عام 1960 م واستمر الى عام1992 م"))
    TV_TITLE.add(TvTitlesViewModel(R.drawable.abdelbasset_abdessamad, "برنامج على مائدة الأفطار", "برنامج على مائدة الافطار من تقديم الشيخ علي الطنطاوي رحمه الله, تم بث أول حلقة منه في عام 1960 م واستمر الى عام1992 م"))
    TV_TITLE.add(TvTitlesViewModel(R.drawable.abdelbasset_abdessamad, "برنامج على مائدة الأفطار", "برنامج على مائدة الافطار من تقديم الشيخ علي الطنطاوي رحمه الله, تم بث أول حلقة منه في عام 1960 م واستمر الى عام1992 م"))
    TV_TITLE.add(TvTitlesViewModel(R.drawable.abdelbasset_abdessamad, "برنامج على مائدة الأفطار", "برنامج على مائدة الافطار من تقديم الشيخ علي الطنطاوي رحمه الله, تم بث أول حلقة منه في عام 1960 م واستمر الى عام1992 م"))

}
```

P.C. I didn't add any codes in my second fragment

**Here is a pic of my recycler view**

[image]

**If the user clicks the button I need to pass the title value and swipe to the second fragment**

**my second fragment pic**
[image]

Comment: Hope you will find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829707/how-to-pass-or-send-data-from-recyclerview-adapter-to-fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With kotlin, you can use High Order function to call callback instead of creating interface like java.

Create a high order function in the Adapter's constructor. Then when you set click then you invoke and get that invoked data in view. As follows:

```
// You should change the class name to uppercase. Like `TvTitleAdapter`
class tvTitleAdapter (
    val context: Context, 
    val TITLE_LIST : ArrayList<TvTitlesViewModel>,
    private val onClick: ((tvTitleName: String) -> Unit)? = null // Pass the param you want. Here I try to pass String with name tvTitleName.
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<tvTitleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...
        holder.tvTitleButton.setOnClickListener {
            when(position){
                0 -> {
                    onClick?.invoke(`your title`) // Pass your title in invoke.
                }
                else -> return@setOnClickListener
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the initialization of `TvTitleAdapter`, you declare the `onClick` param. It will listen to the callback when you call `invoke()`.

```
class TvTitlesFragment : Fragment() {
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        val adapter = tvTitleAdapter(
            requireContext(), 
            TV_TITLE,
            onClick = { tvTitleName ->
                // This code opens the `Second Fragment` with `tvTitleName` passed by the `newInstance()` function.
                requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, SecondFragment.newInstance(tvTitleName))
                    .commit()
            } 
        )
    }
}
```

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {
    
    ...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        // Get data from `TvTitlesFragment`
        val tvTitleName = argument?.getString(KEY_TV_TITLE_NAME)
        
        // Set data to your title
        binding.tvTitle.text = tvTitleName
    }

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_TV_TITLE_NAME = "KEY_TV_TITLE_NAME"

        // Create `SecondFragment` with bundle so you can send data from certain fragment to `SecondFragment`.
        fun newInstance(tvTitleName: String) : SecondFragment = SecondFragment().apply {
            val bundle = bundleOf(KEY_TV_TITLE_NAME to tvTitleName)
            arguments = bundle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to pass the data to the second fragment? ... I want to pass the title to the second fragment

Comment: @Abood 
Inside the `onClick{}` block, you can completely pass `tvTitleName` to another fragment. Above I solved for you the problem of how to get data from `RecyclerView.Adapter` to `Fragment`. The rest is how you use the data you get, I'm not sure. Because I don't know you are using Navigation Component or you are using `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()` to open another Fragment.

Comment: when the user clicks the button, I need it to open the second fragment and pass tvTitleName value " I don't know how to open or swipe to the other fragment by a button click "

Comment: it will be a huge help if u updated your question showing the answer of question one

Comment: @Abood So I want to ask a question? Are you using Navigation Component for your project? I need to know so I can help you as best I can.

Comment: no, I didn't use the Navigation Component in my fragments

Comment: the app crashes because of this code replace(R.id.your_fragment_container) .. I tried adding an id to linear layout and a frame layout and still crashes

Comment: do I have to add a frame layout (with id) to the bottom-sheet-fragments and delete the view-pager?

Comment: If your behavior doesn't need the view pager, you can completely remove it. What you should do is a parent bottom sheet and inside include `TvTitlesFragment` and `SecondFragment`. In the `BottomSheet` layout, you add a frame layout. That Frame Layout helps you to display child fragments as `TvTitlesFragment` or `SecondFragment`. And change my code from `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager` to `getFragmentManager().supportFragmentManager` where `replace` is the id of the frame layout you just created in `BottomSheet`.

Comment: I tried your code and I always get this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a00d3 (com.gazelle.Gasseleapp:id/fragmentContainer) for fragment TvTitlesFragment .. I really don't know what to do. if you have any blogs or tutorials that help me do the transaction I would appreciated it since it's the first time I use your code

Comment: finally, after a long time of learning, I was able to solve it using your code but I changed 'requireActivity().supportFragmentManager' to 'fragmentManger' and in the main fragment where the container is located I changed 'supportFragmentManager' to 'childFragmentManager'